# Android Plugin Architecture Tutorial

Tags: android

I am following this tutorial to make a plugin architecture for my Android app:

http://androidsrc.net/creating-android-app-plugin-architecture-tutorial/

I completed the tutorial but when I run the project I get this error:

Error:(6, 24) error: package com.example.aidl does not exist

But I am using the same structure of packages that tutorial is using.

Is there anything that I have to add to my project code?

Answer (score 1):

I recently developed a plugin architecture like this for an Android app. I initially considered using AIDL, but settled on broadcasting Intents instead. The [source](https://github.com/reshaping-the-future/better-together) is available (Apache 2.0) if you're interested.

In particular, look at the [plugin host](https://github.com/reshaping-the-future/better-together/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ac/robinson/bettertogether/host) part of the code, where the work of searching for and launching plugin activities happens.